# How to use JPA 2.0 @ManyToMany without issues

Tags: hibernate, jpa, struts2, jpa-2.0

I am using `JPA 2.0` and `Spring` in my development. My entity class contains two `@ManyToMany` relationships.

```
@Entity("payment")
 public class PaymentData implements Serializable
{
    private Long pk;

    private Collection<PaymentItemData> paymentItem;
    /**
     *  minorPaymentItem
     *
     */
    private Collection<MinorPayItemData> minorPaymentItem;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "payitem_m_assig",
    joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = false),
    inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "minor_pay_item_id", nullable = false))
    public Collection<MinorPayItemData> getMinorPaymentItem()
    {
        return minorPaymentItem;
    }

    /**
     * @param minorPaymentItem the minorPaymentItem to set
     */
    public void setMinorPaymentItem(final Collection<MinorPayItemData> value)
    {
        this.minorPaymentItem = value;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "payitem_assigned",
    joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = false),
    inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = false))
    public Collection<PaymentItemData> getPaymentItem()
    {
        return paymentItem;
    }

    /**
     * Set the property paymentItem
     *
     * @param value -paymentItem
     *
     */
    public void setPaymentItem(final Collection<PaymentItemData> value)
    {
        this.paymentItem = value;
    }    

}
```

When i run a query to retrieve records from the payment table in the database, like

```
Query q = manager.createQuery("select a from PaymentData a");
q.getResultList();
```

If i allow the `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on the `@ManyToMany`, I get the following errors

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.postInstantiate(BasicLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoader.createBatchingEntityLoader(BatchingEntityLoader.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1937)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3205)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3191)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.postInstantiate(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 39 more
```

But if i remove `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` and leave it as `@ManyToMany`, i will have the exception

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.data.PaymentData.paymentItem, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:506)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at com.niu.util.Util.toString(Util.java:131)
    at com.niu.util.data.BaseData.toString(BaseData.java:107)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:771)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler.println(SystemLogHandler.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1861.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.niu.web.common.interceptor.ApplicationModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ApplicationModelDrivenInterceptor.java:31)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid the `MultipleBagFetchException`, instead of using `FetchType.EAGER`, try using the `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` as in this example:

```
@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(name = "payitem_m_assig", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pay_item_id", nullable = e), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "minor_pay_item_id", nullable = false))
public Collection<MinorPayItemData> getMinorPaymentItem()
{
    return minorPaymentItem;
}
```

Here is a small description of from the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/):

- > @LazyCollection: defines the lazyness option on @ManyToMany and
  >   @OneToMany associations. LazyCollectionOption can be TRUE (the
  >   collection is lazy and will be loaded when its state is accessed),
  >   EXTRA (the collection is lazy and all operations will try to avoid the
  >   collection loading, this is especially useful for huge collections
  >   when loading all the elements is not necessary) and FALSE (association
  >   not lazy)
- > @Fetch: defines the fetching strategy used to load the association.
  >   FetchMode can be SELECT (a select is triggered when the association
  >   needs to be loaded), SUBSELECT (only available for collections, use a
  >   subselect strategy - please refers to the Hibernate Reference
  >   Documentation for more information) or JOIN (use a SQL JOIN to load
  >   the association while loading the owner entity). JOIN overrides any
  >   lazy attribute (an association loaded through a JOIN strategy cannot
  >   be lazy).

I hope it helps

Comment: It worked seamlessly. What if i change to eclipse link JPA implementation, won't it break the code.

Comment: @Uchenna Indeed there are differences in JPA implementations. For portability reasons you should avoid specific features. This as far as I know is a Hibernate specific one, but also issues that exist in one implementation may not occurr in another. So I think the best is to deal with the problem at hand.

Comment: @RodrigoS.Bento: does it work because the default fetch mode of a LazyCollection is SELECT rather than JOIN?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to make the XxxtoMany associations lazy (the default). This way, the collections will only be loaded when needed, or when you tell Hibernate to fetch them eagerly using a query with a join fetch clause. Making them EAGER forces Hibernate to *always* load them, even when you don't need them.

Of course, if you need them and they are configured as LAZY, they can only be loaded if the session is still open. Once the session is closed, the entity becomes detached, and the collections can't be lazy-loaded anymore. You thus need to initialize them explicitly (by calling a method of the collection, or by invoking `Hibernate.initialize(collection)`) before closing the session.

If you really want to keep them eagerly loaded, then only one of them should be a bag (i.e. of type `Collection` or `List`). The others should be declared as `Set`.

Side note: the mapping of the second association is wrong: you're using the same join column twice.

Comment: Thanks for your observation and response. I am going to change both to Set and keep the eagerly loaded and see if it works. In as much as this is working now, it is my desire to make the code portable.