# Hibernate: MultipleBagFetchException when using entity graph

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate version 4.3.5:

I experience some strange behaviour when I try to eagerly fetch two relations that I defined as lists.
It works perfectly fine to load the entity with a normal query, but as soon as I try to use an entity graph,
I get an exception: MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

So, my question is: why does this happen and how can I fix it?

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Person.loadAll",
         attributeNodes = {
         @NamedAttributeNode(value = "managedPersons", subgraph = "personName"),
         @NamedAttributeNode(value = "incidents", subgraph = "incidentNumber")},
         subgraphs = {
               @NamedSubgraph(name = "personName",
                     attributeNodes = {
                     @NamedAttributeNode("name")
               }),
               @NamedSubgraph(name = "incidentNumber",
               attributeNodes = {
                     @NamedAttributeNode("number")
               })
})
public class Person {

   private long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "managerid")
   private Person manager;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @OrderBy("name ASC")
   private List<Person> managedPersons;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "caller", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @OrderBy("number ASC")
   private List<Incident> incidents;

   //some more stuff...
}
```

Comment: Look that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769656/how-to-use-jpa-2-0-manytomany-without-issues/10769858#10769858

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: Do you have any news?